# how to Display javascript variables in HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

this my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var save_method; //for save method string
var table, ket;
function edit_user(id)
{
save_method = 'update';
ket = "disabledInput";
}

 </script>
```

my html

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <input id="ket" placeholder="NPP" class="form-control" type="text">
    <span class="help-block" id="method"></span>
</div>
```

No error appears but my variable is not shown. Can anybody suggest how to solve it?

Comment: Javascript is not php. You can't break into a script tag in the middle of an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html code

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="id" placeholder="NPP"

    class="form-control" type="text" id="test">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>



 <script type="text/javascript">

var save_method; //for save method string
var table;
var ket;
function edit_user(id)
{
save_method = 'update';
ket = "disabledInput";
document.getElementById("test").value ="disabledInput";//to assign textbox value
}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply execute js within id tag. What you can done instead is to attach onload event to body html element

```
<body onload="setInputId()">
```

**setInputId** function should perform manipulation with id of your input.

```
function setInputId(){ getElementsByName['id'][0].setAttribute("id", ket);}
```